# Amazon Connect - Amazon Lex slot reading prompt at the end of flow?

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

I am building an IVR in Amazon Connect that accepts voice input using Amazon Lex integrations. I have set up a collectName intent to collect the user's first and last name but the slot is prompting for last name at the end of the flow after other questions have been asked.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

My current setup is an intent called collectName with a AMAZON.FirstName and AMAZON.LastName slots with prompts that prompt for them. However, the prompt is asking for full name and we continue throughout the flow. At the end of the flow, it is prompting for last name.

Comment: Can you share at least a diagram depicting your flow? Do you have any CDK, CloudFormation or Terraform definition of your amazon connect instance?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I can't be sure but it sounds like you haven't got your utterance for the intent setup correctly. It should have the entry `{firstName} {lastName}`, where `firstName` and `lastName` are the names of the slots you have created.